# #Jiglib AS3#Away3d press down event listener on object3d

Tags: actionscript-3

My personal project uses Away3D as 3D engine and Jiglib as physic engine. And Jiglib supports Away3D as a plug-in just like PaperVision3D. Basically, I managed to create cubes bouncing and colliding with each other. However, I need more user interactive whenever user press down on the cube, in more specific term: able to throw away or drag the cube when user hold down to the cube. In Jiglib combined with PaperVision3D, some managed to do that by using:

```
mesh.addEventListener(InteractiveScene3DEvent.OBJECT_PRESS, objectPressHandler);
private function objectPressHandler(event:InteractiveScene3DEvent):void
    {
        //get ref.
        pActive = event.displayObject3D;            
        //create constriant
        jMouseConstraint = new MouseConstraint(pActive, new Number3D(0, 0, 1), camera, viewport);


        //add listener for  mouse up.
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, removeMouseConstraint);
    }

    private function removeMouseConstraint(e:MouseEvent):void
    {

        //kill listener
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, removeMouseConstraint);
        //kill the contraint
        jMouseConstraint.destroy();
        //garbage
        jMouseConstraint = null;
    }
```

However I don't know how to achieve the same thing with Jiglib combined with Away3D. Any help?

Comment: I don't think you need to add the event listeners to the stage but rather to the objects themselves.